# Python script that uploads a file without using a form and just uses Flask as API

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file from my desktop to Flask running on my local machine without using a web form at all.  I have looked at the examples for BOTH Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and [Poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/).

Here is the code for my Flask API

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/upload', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['files']
        f.save('/Users/djangod/newTest.txt')
        return '200'
    else:
        return 'Upload Page'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Here is the code from my Python script using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload"
files = {'file': open('/Users/djangod/text.txt', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I get an error 400 and cannot figure out why but for some strange reason running this curl command works

```
curl -i -X POST -F files=@test.txt http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload
```

I initially thought Flask was configured incorrectly, until curl worked. I am running on OS X 10.8.5 and using virtualenv. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your requests code is wrong (probably a typo). Below is what's different between what should work and what you have:

```
files = {'files': open('/Users/djangod/text.txt', 'rb')}
#             ^ missing an s
```

You're telling Flask to look for a file called `'files'` so you need to tell requests to send that as the filename.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it was something stupid on my part.  That'll teach me to code and watch college football at the same time.

Comment: Update: The typo actually exists in Requests official documentation. I just copied and pasted it :(

Comment: No worries. Submit a pull request and add yourself to the AUTHORS.rst. We merge documentation PRs ASAP.